# quitar elementos con uno o mas valores duplicados Java

Tags: java, oracle, spring

vengo a solicitar vuestra ayuda, tengo una lista que obtengo desde una base de datos, pero necesito excluir todos los registros que tengan 1 o mas valores duplicados segun una llave compuesta.
Por ejemplo tengo lo siguiente, la llave a evualuar son los campos valor1, valor2,valor3 y valor4

```
Fila Numero     Nombre    Valor1  Valor2  Valor3 Valor4
1    123        Test      02      02      03     04
2    123        Test      01      02      03     04
3    123        Test      01      02      03     04
4    123        Test      01      02      03     04
5    123        Test      07      03      03     04
6    123        Test      01      02      04     04
7    123        Test      01      02      04     04
8    123        Test      01      02      04     04
9    123        Test      01      02      04     05
10   123        Test      05      02      04     04
```

En este caso por ejemplo todos los que tengan aun que sea 1 valor repetido, deben quedar fuera. de la lista que puse solo pasarían los registros de la fila:1,5 y 10.

La forma que en la que interactuo con la lista es mediante el metodo write() de un `public void write(List<? extends T> items)`

habra alguna forma de hacer con java 8 ?

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma simple seria utilizar un estructura de tipo **Set** la cual no permite objetos duplicados, bastaria con sobrescribir el metodo **equals** de tu objeto con el criterio que necesites para identificar si dos objetos son iguales una vez hecho eso tu estructura **Set**  se encargara aplicara ese criterio.

Te muestro un ejemplo simple.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Entity> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Entity(02,02,03,04));
        items.add(new Entity(02,02,03,04));
        items.add(new Entity(02,02,03,05));

        Set<Entity> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>();
        uniqueValues.addAll(items);


        for(Entity e: uniqueValues){
            System.out.println(e.getV1()+ " "+e.getV2()+" "+e.getV3()+" "+e.getV4());
        }
    }
}

class Entity{
    private int v1;
    private int v2;
    private int v3;
    private int v4;

    public Entity(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
        this.v3 = v3;
        this.v4 = v4;
    }

    public int getV4() {
        return v4;
    }

    public void setV4(int v4) {
        this.v4 = v4;
    }

    public int getV1() {
        return v1;
    }

    public void setV1(int v1) {
        this.v1 = v1;
    }

    public int getV2() {
        return v2;
    }

    public void setV2(int v2) {
        this.v2 = v2;
    }

    public int getV3() {
        return v3;
    }

    public void setV3(int v3) {
        this.v3 = v3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Entity entity = (Entity) o;
        return v1 == entity.v1 &&
                v2 == entity.v2 &&
                v3 == entity.v3 &&
                v4 == entity.v4;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(v1, v2, v3, v4);
    }
}
```

Cualquier duda dejalo en la caja de comentarios.
Saludos.